# Debug my simple javascript for loop please

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
function skl() {
    var trct = 100;
    var amt = 100;
    while (amt == trct)
    {
        funk();
        amt += 50;
        trct = counttr();
    }
    console.log(amt, friendct);
};
```

Initially there are 100 `<tr>s`

`funk()` scrolls down to reveal 50 more `<tr>`s

`counttr()` counts the amount of TRs and returns the amount.

The point of the function is to scroll down until their is no more TRs. When there are no more `<tr>`s the function will still add 50 to `amt` but `counttr()` wont add 50, so when the for loop evaluates the numbers will no longer be equal to each other and the loop ends.

Edit - The loop only runs once and displays "100 150" meaning the value of `trct` didn't change.

Comment: A `while` statement would fit your needs better, I think.

Comment: You mean, it logs `"150 100"`, not `"100 150"`, right? If so, your `counttr` function reports an incorrect value. Either that, or `funk` fails to add more TRs.

Comment: The code for the `counttr()` function would be interesting.

Comment: Btw, it's TRs, not TR's (no apostrophe)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas if you would post an answer in regards to the variable not updating after iteration i will accept it as the answer. I'm assuming the variable update function needs to be delayed and thats what i will work on. thanks for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second clause in a for-loop condition is tested on every iteration, and when it is no longer true, the loop is over.

Your for loop looks like this:

```
for (amt; amt == trct;)
```

If `amt != trct` after the first iteration, the for loop never runs a second time. You'll need to figure out why that's not the case. I would log three things a the end of the for loop, fro some visibility: `amt`, `trct`, and `amt == trct`.

It's possible that the counttr() function is returning something that you're not expecting

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is that `trct` didn't update on the first iteration.

Comment: I try the counttr function after it fails to run a second time and it displays the correct amount. I believe the problem may be the fact that i need to delay the iterations.